# Quando se trata do "list" do Python, é errado chamar de "array"?

Tags: python, terminologia

Em uma resposta dada a uma pergunta que fiz aqui no site, corrigi um usuário que escreveu "array" quando se referia a um "list" do Python.

Fiz isso por questão de ser uma nomenclatura comum a ser usada no Python, apesar de saber que o `list` do Python é bem parecido com o `array` de outras linguagens (como o Javascript, por exemplo).

Mas tecnicamente, seria errado falar "array" quando estamos falando de um "list" do Python?

E se for olhar a funcionalidade, existe diferença alguma diferença entre uma "lista" e um  "array"?

<sub>**Nota**: Preferi não levar em consideraçao o *array* do PHP, pelo fato de nesta linguagem o *array* ser algo mais exótico se comparado à outras linguagens que utilizam esse termo.</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sim, tecnicamente é errado - e vale a pena comentar quando os termos são usados sem diferenciação.

O primeiro fator é que *existem* arrays em Python - tanto na biblioteca padrão, no módulo `array`, como o objeto nativo `bytearray`. (E as muito usadas arrays do numpy).

E o segundo fator é que em geral, quando falamos em Array em programação em geral, sem estarmos falando de uma linguagem específica, fazemos referência a uma estrutura de dados pré-alocada com um tamanho fixo.

Mesmo que em outras linguagens dinâmicas o que é chamado de array em geral não se refira a algo desse tipo - com tamanho fixo - em lógica de programação,e em muitas linguagens, a distinção existe sim. E nesse sentido as listas de Python são bem diferentes de arrays por que nem sequer há uma sintaxe para cria-las com umm tamanho fixo, pre-definido (e no caso de arrays multi-dimensionais, sequer há uma forma óbvia, se quiser mimetizar o comportamento com listas).

Não impede que em conversas informais e mesmo ocasionalmente de forma escrita, onde está se tratando de dados que serão usados no front-end por javascript e no back por Python, alguém diga array. Mesmo por que esses dados serão trocados em estruturas JSON, onde o nome delas é Array, por conta da herança do Javascript.