# Como o Python trata e representa um array internamente?

Tags: python, array, característica-linguagem, python-internals, cpython

Em Python qualquer tipo de array é do tipo da classe `list`, veja:

```
array = ['Gato', 'Jake', 'Finn']
print(type(array))
```

Saída:

> `<class 'list'>`

Ou seja, todo array é um objeto de `list`. No entanto, há uma questão que eu sempre tive na minha mente, que seria a forma que o Python trata um array *internamente*, e qual seria o tipo de estrutura de dados que a classe `list` usa para guardar os valores do array.

Sendo assim, eu gostaria de ter minhas dúvidas esclarecidas.

## Dúvidas

1. Como um array é representado internamente no Python?
2. Qual estrutura de dados é usada internamente para representar e
   possibilitar a manipulação do array, lista-encadeada, tabela hash ou
   um array simples com alocação dinâmica?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Primeiro, *array* é diferente de lista.

- [Quando se trata do "list" do Python, é errado chamar de "array"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/171023/5878)

Em muitos casos, comumente mais informações, o erro de nomenclatura não será um agravante e não prejudicará a comunicação, mas dado que estaremos analisando o funcionamento interno da linguagem julgo ser interessante se ater aos termos corretos. Dadas as perguntas, ficou claro que a dúvida é sobre o funcionamento de listas, não de *arrays*.

O tipo `list` é nativo do Python e foi implementado em C sob a estrutura `PyListObject`.

```c
typedef struct {
    PyVarObject ob_base;
    /* Vector of pointers to list elements.  list[0] is ob_item[0], etc. */
    PyObject **ob_item;

    /* ob_item contains space for 'allocated' elements.  The number
     * currently in use is ob_size.
     * Invariants:
     *     0 <= ob_size <= allocated
     *     len(list) == ob_size
     *     ob_item == NULL implies ob_size == allocated == 0
     * list.sort() temporarily sets allocated to -1 to detect mutations.
     *
     * Items must normally not be NULL, except during construction when
     * the list is not yet visible outside the function that builds it.
     */
    Py_ssize_t allocated;
} PyListObject;
```

Onde temos:

- `ob_base`, um objeto que representa estruturas de tamanho variável, implementa o campo `ob_size`;
- `ob_item`, um ponteiro para ponteiro de `PyObject`;
- `allocated`, um objeto `Py_ssize_t` que representa o tamanho alocado;

Como pode ver - inclusive comentado no código - os itens que compõem a lista no Python serão gerenciados a partir de `ob_item`. Ele, por ser um ponteiro, possui a dinamicidade de ser realocado conforme a necessidade de crescimento da lista, em que cada posição apontará para um outro ponteiro `PyObject` que representa o item da lista. Vale lembrar aqui que **todas** as estruturas que o Python implementa herdam de `PyObject`, então não haverá restrições do tipo que poderá ser armazenado na lista.

Sempre que o tamanho de uma lista precisa ser alterado, a função `list_resize` é invocada; ela que é responsável pela implementação do algoritmo de realocação de uma lista.

- [Por que essas duas formas de inicializar a mesma lista em Python geram estruturas de tamanhos diferentes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/319164/5878)

O código fonte desta função é:

```c
/* Ensure ob_item has room for at least newsize elements, and set
 * ob_size to newsize.  If newsize > ob_size on entry, the content
 * of the new slots at exit is undefined heap trash; it's the caller's
 * responsibility to overwrite them with sane values.
 * The number of allocated elements may grow, shrink, or stay the same.
 * Failure is impossible if newsize <= self.allocated on entry, although
 * that partly relies on an assumption that the system realloc() never
 * fails when passed a number of bytes <= the number of bytes last
 * allocated (the C standard doesn't guarantee this, but it's hard to
 * imagine a realloc implementation where it wouldn't be true).
 * Note that self->ob_item may change, and even if newsize is less
 * than ob_size on entry.
 */
static int
list_resize(PyListObject *self, Py_ssize_t newsize)
{
    PyObject **items;
    size_t new_allocated;
    Py_ssize_t allocated = self->allocated;

    /* Bypass realloc() when a previous overallocation is large enough
       to accommodate the newsize.  If the newsize falls lower than half
       the allocated size, then proceed with the realloc() to shrink the list.
    */
    if (allocated >= newsize && newsize >= (allocated >> 1)) {
        assert(self->ob_item != NULL || newsize == 0);
        Py_SIZE(self) = newsize;
        return 0;
    }

    /* This over-allocates proportional to the list size, making room
     * for additional growth.  The over-allocation is mild, but is
     * enough to give linear-time amortized behavior over a long
     * sequence of appends() in the presence of a poorly-performing
     * system realloc().
     * The growth pattern is:  0, 4, 8, 16, 25, 35, 46, 58, 72, 88, ...
     */
    new_allocated = (newsize >> 3) + (newsize < 9 ? 3 : 6);

    /* check for integer overflow */
    if (new_allocated > PY_SIZE_MAX - newsize) {
        PyErr_NoMemory();
        return -1;
    } else {
        new_allocated += newsize;
    }

    if (newsize == 0)
        new_allocated = 0;
    items = self->ob_item;
    if (new_allocated <= (PY_SIZE_MAX / sizeof(PyObject *)))
        PyMem_RESIZE(items, PyObject *, new_allocated);
    else
        items = NULL;
    if (items == NULL) {
        PyErr_NoMemory();
        return -1;
    }
    self->ob_item = items;
    Py_SIZE(self) = newsize;
    self->allocated = new_allocated;
    return 0;
}
```

Assim como o Maniero comentou em sua resposta, basicamente o Python aloca um novo espaço de memória já considerando o novo tamanho da lista e considerando espaços de sobra para depois copiar o conteúdo para esse espaço na memória. Perceba que o espaço adicionado ao tamanho da lista será proporcional ao tamanho atual e é feito isso justamente para buscar uma amortização linear no tempo de realocação. Isto é, é mais fácil realocar um espaço maior uma vez e inserir vários elementos do que realocar sempre que for inserir. Perceba também que toda a realocação é feita sobre o objeto `items` e não diretamente sobre `self->ob_item`:

```c
items = self->ob_item;

if (new_allocated <= (PY_SIZE_MAX / sizeof(PyObject *)))
    PyMem_RESIZE(items, PyObject *, new_allocated);
else
    items = NULL;

if (items == NULL) {
    PyErr_NoMemory();
    return -1;
}

self->ob_item = items;
```

`PyMem_RESIZE` é uma macro definida por:

```c
#define PyMem_RESIZE(p, type, n) \
  ( (p) = ((size_t)(n) > PY_SSIZE_T_MAX / sizeof(type)) ? NULL :        \
        (type *) PyMem_REALLOC((p), (n) * sizeof(type)) )
```

Que basicamente faz a realocação de memória no ponteiro especificado.

Answer (score 10):

Antes de mais nada entenda que Python é uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica e precisa de estruturas de dados para lidar com esta necessidade. Você não acessa o dado de forma direta como em linguagens estáticas. Se quiser saber mais sobre essa questão de tipagem leia [Como funciona internamente os arrays do PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/361149/101).

Assim como em PHP, Python tem uma `struct` com uma `union` (ambas linguagens são escritas em C) com o dado e seu tipo, sendo que o dado pode ser um ponteiro.

A lista tem uma estrutura com um cabeçalho, o que seria mais ou menos o normal se escrito em C mesmo em algo mais sofisticado e um objeto com uma sequência de dados. Estes dados serão etas estruturas que citei no parágrafo anterior. Em C um *array* é justamente uma sequência de dados acessado por um ponteiro. Então a lista do Python não é diferente do *array* do C e é tão eficiente quanto se olharmos só para a lista em si. A ineficiência viria só ao acesso ao dado que tem um controle interno. Pode-se dizer que que Python precisa desse cabeçalho, mas mesmo em C para usar o *array* de forma conveniente e correta em código real você precisa de algo assim.

Este cabeçalho tem basicamente o tamanho da lista, o ponteiro para o objeto lista em si e um objeto que é o início da lista (ainda preciso entendê-lo). Pode mudar de versão para versão.

A diferença clara entre uma lista e um *array* é que o segundo costuma ser definido como uma estrutura fixa e não pode mudar de tamanho e a lista pode. Internamente só tem duas formas de mudar o tamanho de uma coleção, ou faz uma lista ligada (ou algo parecido) que permite adicionar elementos novos de forma simples e sob demanda, porém o acesso ao dado fica trágico ou faz como um *array* com sobra de capacidade (aloca mais que precisa) e quando estourar a capacidade você cria outro *array* e copia tudo para este novo e descarta o antigo. Isso é o normal em praticamente todas as linguagens e costuma ser chamado de [*array* dinâmico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array). O nome não tem a ver com a alocação que por acaso é feita dinamicamente com `malloc()` (mesmo que indiretamente).

Note que isto vale para CPython que é a implementação padrão, outras implementações podem fazer de forma muito diferente, mas como elas devem funcionar de forma compatível e não poderá ser tão diferente assim. [Fonte](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#how-are-lists-implemented-in-cpython). Por exemplo Jython pode usar o própria `ArrayList` da JVM que tem a mesma semântica.

Já um `dict` é bem diferente porque aí é usada uma forma de *hashtable*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

> Como um array é representado internamente no Python?

Array é representado como uma lista no python.
existe a biblioteca do `array` exemplo:

```
from array import *

x = array('i', [10,20,30,40,50])
print(type(x))
```

mas array nao suporta string apenas:

'b'   signed char
'B'   unsigned char 
'u'   Py_UNICODE
'h'   signed short
'H'   unsigned short
... Ver mais em [Array Tipos](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/array.html)

existe uma biblioteca de array com mais recursos chamada NumPy, exemplo de uso:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(['Gato', 'Jake', 'Finn'])
print(type(a))
```

> Qual estrutura de dados é usada internamente para representar e
>   possibilitar a manipulação do array, lista-encadeada, tabela hash ou
>   um array simples com alocação dinâmica?

Nao consigo informar ao certo pela falta de informacao na documentacao do python.